# Spatial autocorrelation machine learning python

Tags: machine-learning, python, random-forest, autocorrelation, spatial

I am trying to build a machine learning model for spatiotemporal data. My predictors are all monthly climate variables, and as such display spatial autocorrelation. The target dataset however has relatively low spatial autocorrelation (it is quite noisy). What is the procedure for a robust estimate? One method I have seen being mentioned is to combine the random forest with a kriging approach, i.e. to fit a random forest to the training data and then combine the random forest prediction with kriging applied to the random forest residuals.

Is this a robust way to tackle spatial auto-correlation? Others mention to apply a spatial cross validation. Is there a preferred way, and if so are there any typical python libraries that can help me achieve this? I know that in R there are libraries specifically for spatial datasets but as far as I can tell they don't exist in python.